# Proving $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{ab} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor}{b} \right\rfloor$ for $a,b>1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to prove rigorously the following:

> $$\left\lfloor \frac{x}{ab} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor}{b} \right\rfloor$$   for integers $a,b \geq 1$ and real $x$.

So far I haven't gotten far. It's enough to prove this instead:

> $$\left\lfloor \frac{z}{c} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor z \rfloor}{c} \right\rfloor$$   for integers $c \geq 1$ and real $z$

since we can just put $z=\lfloor x/a \rfloor$ and $c=b$.

Comment: Just to say, it's not homework.

Comment: hint: Start with $x=qa+r$ and $q=q'b+r'$ ($0\le r <a$ and $0\le r' <b$) then
$$x=q'ab+(ar'+r)\ \ \text{with $\ 0\le ar'+r < a(b-1)+a$}$$

Comment: @hermionestranger You might also like to note that in the statement of the problem, we require $a$ and $b$ to be integers, as the result is not true otherwise.

Comment: @OldJohn Actually, you just need $b$ to be an integer.

Comment: Also, $b>1$ is stricter than needed; $b=1$ trivially works, too.

Answer (score 10):

It is *trivial* when done *universally*, i.e. using the universal definition of floor

$\begin{align}  k\,&\le\, \lfloor x\rfloor \color{#c00}{\iff} k\,\le\, x,\quad {\rm for\ all}\,\ k\in\Bbb Z\\[1em]
{\bf Lemma}\qquad\quad\color{#0a0}{\lfloor r/n\rfloor}\,& =\, \lfloor{\lfloor r\rfloor}/n\rfloor\ \ {\rm 
for}\ \ 0<n\in\Bbb Z,\,\ r\in\Bbb R\\[.6em]
{\bf Proof}\qquad\qquad\quad\ \ \  k \,&\le \lfloor{\lfloor r\rfloor}/n\rfloor\\[.4em]
\color{#c00}\iff\quad k\ & \le\ \:{\lfloor r\rfloor}/n\\[.2em]
\overset{\times\, n}\iff\ \ nk\ &\le\ \ \lfloor r\rfloor\qquad {\rm by}\,\  n>0\\[.4em]
\color{#c00}\iff\ \ nk\ &\le\,\ \ \ r\qquad\ \  {\rm  by}\,\  n\in\Bbb Z\\[.2em]
\overset{\div\,n}\iff\ \ \ \ k\ &\le\:\ \ \ r/n\quad\  {\rm by}\,\  n>0\\[.4em]
\color{#c00}\iff\ \ \ \  k\ &\le\ \ \color{#0a0}{\lfloor r/n\rfloor}\quad {\small\bf QED}
\end{align}$

Yours is special case $\ r = x/a,\,\ n = b.$

Re: universality: see the links in comments below for more general (category-theoretic) viewpoints.

Comment: +1 for the nice proof technique $\;\langle \forall k :: k \leq E \iff k \leq F \rangle \iff E = F\;$ (assuming $\;k,E,F\;$ are all integers, or all reals).  That was unknown to me, and in retrospect blindingly obvious.  This should have been the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I just found Dijkstra's [EWD1315](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1315.html), which states that such proofs are known as "proofs by indirect equality".

Comment: @Marnix I've never heard that term before. Perhaps it is  specific to computer science. If you want to view it more generally one can use ideas from category theory, viz. that ceiling,floor are [left,right adjoints](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/6783/242) to the inclusion $\,\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb R,\,$ and [Yoneda's Lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149376/excessive-use-of-the-yoneda-lemma). Such viewpoints are mentioned [numerous times here.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+%28ceiling+OR+floor%29+%28yoneda+OR+adjoint+OR+adjunction+OR+universal%29)

Answer (score 6):

This theorem is not true if $b$ is not an integer.  Take $x=b=1.5$ and take $a=1$.

If $b$ is an integer, this follows from the rule $$\left\lfloor \frac{y}{b}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}b\right\rfloor$$

Setting $y=\frac x a$.

Showing this rule, then, suffices.

Let $y = \lfloor y \rfloor + \{y\}$, where $0\leq \{y\} < 1$.

Use division algorithm to write $\lfloor y \rfloor = qb + r$ with $0\leq r <b$.

The $\frac{\lfloor y \rfloor} b = q + \frac{r}{b}$, and $0\leq \frac{r}{b} <1$, so

$$\left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}b\right\rfloor = q$$

On the other hand, since $[y]< (q+1)b$, since $0\leq\{y\}<1$, then $y = [y]+\{y\}<(q+1)b$.

So $q \leq \frac y b < q+1$ and again $$\left\lfloor \frac{y}{b}\right\rfloor = q $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lfloor x/a \rfloor$ = c(say)=>x=ca+d 0≤d

Let $\lfloor c/b \rfloor$=e(say)=>c=be+f  0≤f

=>x=ca+d=(be+f)a+d=abe+af+d.

$\frac{x}{a}$=be+f+ $\frac{d}{a}$

$\frac{\frac{x}{a}}{b}$=e+$\frac{f}{b}$+$\frac{d}{ab}$

=>$\lfloor x/a/b \rfloor$ = e = $\lfloor c/b \rfloor$  = $\lfloor \lfloor x/a \rfloor /b \rfloor$

Answer (score 0):

I think following approach is simple and straight-forward.

For real number $x ≥ 0$ and integers $a,b > 0$

Let n be some integer such that $n ≤ x/ab < n+1$.

This implies $n*b ≤ x/a < (n+1)*b$.  (after multiplying every term by b)

Now,

LHS = $⌊/⌋ = n$

RHS = $⌊⌊/⌋/⌋ = ⌊(n*b)/⌋ = ⌊n⌋ = n$

LHS = RHS. Hence, proved.