# Can floor(floor(a/b)/c) ever be different to floor(a/(bc))?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any mathematical proof that the following equality holds true always (across the natural number domain)?

$\lfloor{\frac{\lfloor^a/_b\rfloor}{c}}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\rfloor \quad \textrm{for}\ \ \ a,b,c\ \in\ \mathbb{N}$

In other words, I'm looking for proof that there are no values of `a`, `b`, and `c`, for which a two-step integer-truncation division will give a different result than dividing by the product of the two divisors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{ab} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor}{b} \right\rfloor$ for $a,b \gt 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172823/proving-left-lfloor-fracxab-right-rfloor-left-lfloor-frac-left-lflo)

Answer (score 4):

Given a real number $x$ and an integer $n$, in order to prove $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$ we need to prove two things:

- $n \leq x$, and
- for every integer $m$ with $m \leq x$, we have $m \leq n$.

So, first note that
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{c} \right\rfloor \leq \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{c} \leq \frac{a/b}{c} = \frac{a}{bc}.
$$
Next, if $m$ is any integer with $m \leq a/(bc)$,
\begin{align}
m \leq \frac{a}{bc} 
&\implies mc \leq a/b \\
&\implies mc \leq \lfloor a/b \rfloor \\
&\implies m \leq \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{c} 
 \implies m \leq \left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{c} \right\rfloor.
\end{align}
Thus:
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor a/b \rfloor}{c} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{bc} \right\rfloor.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left\lfloor{\frac{\lfloor^a/_b\rfloor}{c}}\right\rfloor \ne \left\lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\right\rfloor$$

First we prove the following lemma:

*Lemma 1:* Let $p>q$ be 2 non-negative real numbers and $r$ a nonzero natural number. If there is no natural number $m$ such that $p>m>q$ then there is no natural number $n$ such that $p/r>n>q/r$

We can prove it using the contrapositive. If there is a natural number $n$ such that$p/r>n>q/r$ then $m=rn$ is such that $p>m>q$. This completes the proof.

When

$$\frac{a}{b}=\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor$$
it is easy to see that
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{\lfloor^a/_b\rfloor}{c}}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\right\rfloor$$

Next consider the case where
$$\frac{a}{b}>\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor$$
Obviously there's no natural number between the two. Also
$$\frac{a}{bc}>\frac{\lfloor^a/_b\rfloor}{c}$$

and Lemma 1 tells us that there is no natural number between the 2. So we can take the floor of both sides of the inequality to get

$$\left\lfloor{\frac{\lfloor^a/_b\rfloor}{c}}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\right\rfloor$$

This completes the proof.