# Floor and ceiling function relation on positive integers

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to prove that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, the following equality is true:

$$\left\lceil \frac{a}{b}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor\frac{a+b-1}{b}\right\rfloor$$

What have I thought about?

Then $a$ = $qb + r$, where $q$ is the quotient and $r$ the remainder

\begin{align}
b-1 &\ge r \ge 0 \\
qb + (b-1) &\ge qb+r \ge qb \\
qb + (b-1) &\ge a\ge qb \\
\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor +1-\frac1{b} &\ge \frac{a}{b} \ge \left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor \\
\left\lfloor \frac{a+b}{b} \right\rfloor -\frac1{b} &\ge \frac{a}{b} \ge \left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor
\end{align}

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37555/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281710/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft%5Clceil%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%20%3D%20%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bb-1%7D%7Bb%7D%5Cright%5Crfloor%24&p=1)